# Screencapture over cron shown background instead window content

Tags: macos, cron, screenshot, screen-capture, macos-catalina

On macOs Catalina have problems with making screenshots over cron.
When manually run `do_screenshot.sh` script then all fine.
But when it run auto over cron - probs, only menu correct, instead window content shown macOs background(see pic)

`do_screenshot.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DATEFULL=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`
FILENAME="/Users/yak/Documents/screenshots/"$DATEFULL.png
/usr/sbin/screencapture -x $FILENAME
```

[image]

Comment: `man screencapture` says: "SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
     To capture screen content while logged in via ssh, you must launch
     screencapture in the same mach bootstrap hierarchy as loginwindow:

     PID=pid of loginwindow
     sudo launchctl bsexec $PID screencapture [options]"

Comment: When I try that, I get:  sudo launchctl bsexec 162 /usr/sbin/screencapture test.png >
could not create image from display 0 -- any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Ran into this problem after the update too. Spent hours learning the details, here is the why and how. Credit goes to [big-circle](https://superuser.com/users/1123992/big-circle). The original question and answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1510312/mac-screenshot-crontab-only-got-desktop).

The problem is the cron doesn't have screen access.

Here's the solution

1. close SIP (System Integrity Protection).

Make sure your SIP is disabled. To check if SIP is disabled. To to terminal and type `csrutil status`. It should say SIP status: enabled/disabled.
To disable it:

Powerdown Mac, start up again and hold down cmd+r until OS X Utilities window shows up. Open terminal type `csrutil disable`. Restart again, boot into normal mac os.

2. grant write permission to TCC

`sudo chmod 664 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC`

3. grant screencapure privilege to cron and screencapture

   a) CRON:

   ```
      `sudo sqlite3 "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'insert into access values ("kTCCServiceScreenCapture", "/usr/sbin/cron", 1, 1, 1, "", "", "", "UNUSED", "", 0,"")'`
   ```

   b) screencapture:

   ```
      Pre Big Sur:
   `sudo sqlite3 "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'insert into access values ("kTCCServiceScreenCapture", "/usr/sbin/screencapture", 1, 1, 1, "", "", "", "UNUSED", "", 0,"")'`
   ```

   `--------------------------------------------------------------------------`

   ```
      Big Sur and later:
   `sudo sqlite3 "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'insert into access values ("kTCCServiceScreenCapture", "/usr/sbin/screencapture", 1,2,4,1, "", "", "", "UNUSED", "", 0,"")'`
   ```
4. It's probably a good idea to turn SIP back on at this stage. To enable it, follow step 1, and instead of `csrutil disable` just type `csrutil enable`.

Edit @ 2021-12-09T11:58:00+1000: Added in commands for Big Sur and later per comment from [Silvan Mühlemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2454815/silvan-m%c3%bchlemann)

Comment: For step 4, `csrutil clear` can be used instead to re-enable SIP without having to reboot into recovery on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later.

Comment: For Big Sur and later, the command has changed a bit. The following worked for me: 
`sudo sqlite3 "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'insert into access values ("kTCCServiceScreenCapture", "/usr/sbin/screencapture", 1,2,4,1, "", "", "", "UNUSED", "", 0,"")'`
Note the sequence `1,2,4,1`. Refer to https://rainforest.engineering/2021-02-09-macos-tcc/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You should allow your script to use the "Screen Recording" in the "Security & Privacy" system preferences.

Comment: yes, it added into "Screen Recording" as "Terminal"(MacOs detect screen capture and propose add). 
When i run script manually - all fine.  Probs when script started by cron.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: This is the simpler solution and worked for me for running the following  script on the command line. (note: not cron) https://superuser.com/questions/676735/taking-screen-shot-from-mac-by-an-interval Thank you @Cary

Comment: I tried the solution below with manipulating the TCC.db. This resulted in a broken TCC system. This solution worked perfectly. Note: I had to grant /sbin/cron (and not the script itself) the "Screen Recording" permissions. (Using Big Sur)

Comment: Just give the /usr/sbin/cron "Screen Recording" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may start your app in a background from a terminal with a long loop (you need start it manually, that is not good):

```
#!/bin/bash
for value in {1..980}
do
/Users/<username>/record_activity_with_screen_capture.bash
sleep 60
done
echo All done
```

OR

use launchd (instead of cron) for running this script.
There are two examples:

1. [how to start bash script in launchd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093746/osx-create-launchd-service-for-bash-script-execution)
2. [How to add timing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959004/11579367)
3. [calendar example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329458/run-an-applescript-daily-with-launchd)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing with SIP (System Integrity Protection), which is dangerous, but suggested anyways but the top answer, simply give Screen Recording permissions to `/usr/sbin/cron` (or `/sbin/cron` in some MacOS versions I think).

In order to do that:

1. Open System Settings
2. Open Security & Privacy
3. Go to the Privacy tab
4. Go to Screen Recording
5. Click the lock in the bottom left corner and authenticate in order to enable editing the list
6. Now, if cron is listed there and unchecked, check it and the job is done. Likely is not listed there at all and you need to add it manually
7. Click on + below the list of programs
8. In the file picker hit a magic command Cmd+Shift+G, which will show a Go To Folder popup
9. Type: `/usr/sbin` and hit Enter (if you can't find `cron` in the next steps, try `/sbin` here instead)
10. You should see a list of files, all with an icon of a black terminal
11. Find `cron` on the list and hit Open
12. Check the checkbox next to `cron`
13. Wait for your cron to run the command again.

Voila, it should be capturing screenshots now.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to change shebang to #!/bin/sh, or change screencapture to exec screencapture